# How can I convert this php mysql code to SQL which is acceptable by SQL server ?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this below php code which executes some mysql queries , based on some logic , I want to build Plain SQL code which could be imported from sql server .

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks for any help!!!

> ```
> mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `".$mysql_db."`"); --I don't know how with this line
>
> $q = "SHOW FULL TABLES IN ".$mysql_db;
> $q = mysql_query($q);
>
> if($tc==0)  --//don't worry about $tc
> {
>   mysql_query("
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tdagg` ( --And i don't know how with this
>   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `Pais` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `HackingInt` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, --timestamp can be replace by datetime
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; --//I don't understand this line
>   ");
>   mysql_query("
>   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tdagg_accs` (
>   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `Account` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
>   `IP` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
>   `Hacker` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
>   `Fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `Pais` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Undefined',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
>   ");
> }else
> {
>   mysql_query("
>   ALTER TABLE `tdagg_accs` ADD `Pais` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Undefined'
>   ");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='your_dbname')
DROP DATABASE your_dbname

Go

Create DATABASE your_dbname

go

IF EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where name='tdagg')
DROP TABLE tdagg

Go
USE your_dbname
Go
CREATE TABLE tdagg ( 
  ID int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
  Pais varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  HackingInt int NOT NULL,
  Date timestamp NOT NULL
  )
```

same way you can do it for rest of tables

Comment: what are you trying to say ..you just copied my answer in comment.What you want to edit?

Comment: Thanks!!! Can I edit to this?

    IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='your_dbname')

Create DATABASE 'your_dbname'

Go

IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where name='tdagg')

CREATE TABLE tdagg ( 
  ID int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
  Pais varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  HackingInt int NOT NULL,
  Date timestamp NOT NULL
  )

Go

Comment: ohh yeah you can do that

Comment: Sorry! I'm trying to add "enter" char between lines

Comment: I got you..you can use NOT EXISTS there

Comment: Thanks very much!!! can you give me your skype? ^^ may we be friends?

Comment: I dont use skype much...may be u can add me in FB

Comment: I have just tested! "IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='your_dbname')

Create DATABASE 'your_dbname'

Go" not wort And "IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.tables where name='tdagg')

CREATE TABLE tdagg ( 
  ID int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
  Pais varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  HackingInt int NOT NULL,
  Date timestamp NOT NULL
  )

Go" work if I have DB and replace timestamp with datetime

Comment: ok.I will check in FB did you check mu updated query

Comment: Oh! I realize that I don't need to use "IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='your_dbname')

Create DATABASE 'your_dbname'

Go" because always have that DB ^^ I only have to check if table is exists :D Thanks you again and again

Comment: I didn't understand  "Mu Updated query" :( How to create it (php???)?

Comment: check the answer again I have modified it